# Which data structure I should use if the data is mostly sorted?

Tags: c, linux, sorting, data-structures

I have huge amount of data (mainly of type long long) which is mostly sorted (data is spread in different files and in each file data is in sorted format). I need to dump this data into a file in sorted manner. Which data structure should I use. I am thinking about BST.

Is there any other DS I should use which can give me the optimum performance ?

Thanks
Arpit

Comment: So, you want to write the data _sorted_ in the file? Or do you want to sort it in memory and flush it to your file later?

Comment: What is "mostly sorted"? Do you means the items at most a fixed position away from their right position, or that most of the items are in the proper order but two or three are way off?

Comment: @ Zeta. It needs to be done in memory.

Comment: I think insertion sort would be better. I need to read file one section at a time and based on key I can insert the data into linklist and in the   last traverse the link list and get the data. Do you guys think this would be optimum ?

Comment: You cannot sort a link list efficiently. For an nlogn algo on array, it becomes n^2logn for link list. List is not indexed in constant time like arrays do. Hence additional loop is needed. Can't you use dynamically allocated array? since you tagged c++, may be using vector which resizes itself in a steady way if exceeded?

Comment: Do you mean, each of your input files is perfectly sorted and values in them can overlap? Is it possible to simply concatenate them?

Comment: Updated answer with another possible suggestion if dynamic allocation is a problem and you cannot use vector or c++. I am curious, why the down vote? It is good question for SO, and should be an exception for one without code. Up voted to counter.

Comment: Sorry I am not using C++

Comment: Removing the tag then. See my updated answer. May be building a heap for heap sort would be the best solution in your scenario.

Answer (score 4):

Using any additional data structure won't help. Since most of your data is already sorted and you just need to fix the occasional value, use a simple array to extract data, then use **Insertion Sort**.

Insertion sort runs in **O(n)** for mostly presorted data.

However, this depends if you can hold large enough an array in memory or not depending upon your input size.

**Update:**

I wasn't very clear on your definition of "**mostly sorted**". Generally it means *only few elements are not in the precise sorted position*.

However, as you stated further, *'data is in different files where each file is individually sorted'*, then may be it is a good candidate for the sub function call - **Merge** as in merge Sort.

Note that Merge routine, merges two already sorted arrays. If you have say 10 files where each of them is individually sorted for sure, then using Merge routine would only take O(n).

However, if you have even a few off instances where a single file is not perfectly sorted (on its own), you need to use Insertion Sort.

**Update 2:**

OP says he cannot use an array because he cannot know the number of records in advance. Using simple link list is out of question, since that never competes with arrays (sequential vs random access time) in time complexity.

Pointed out in comments, ***using link list is a good idea IF the files are individually sorted and all you need to run on them is the merge procedure*.**

Dynamically allocated arrays are best, if he can predict size at some point. Since c++ tag was used (only removed latter), going for vector would be a good idea, since it can re size comfortably.

Otherwise, one option might be **Heap Sort**, since it would call heapify first i.e. build a heap (so it can *dynamically accommodate* as many elements needed) and **still produce O(nlogn)** complexity. This is still better than trying to use a link list.

Comment: I can not use array since I am not sure how many records are present. @mostly sorted means data in a file is in sorted form. But there are many such files.

Comment: You can use a link list but not an array? A link list does not allow indexing like an array in constant time. So any kind of sorting attempt on link list will take O(n)^3.

Comment: Can't you use dynamic allocation for an array? Since you tagged c++ too - may be vector from STL?

Comment: Linked lists will work fine complexity-wise if all you do is merge, since the only operation that needs to be performed for merge is sequential reads on the input lists and appending to the output list. That being said, it is probably still smarter to use a contiguous approach for locality and space efficiency.

Comment: @ComicSansMS yeah - perfectly said. I simply didn't consider the scenario with only merge and link list with no sorting involved. +1

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you don't need a data structure at all.

If the files are already sorted, you can use the merge part of merge sort, which is O(n), or more generally O(n*log k), where k is the number of files.

Comment: Insertion sort works better than merge sort (up to O(n)) on a presorted array. Just FYI

Comment: FYI: What you just wrote doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I am not sure what to write on a sentence saying "doesn't make any sense". Perhaps the link should explain http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort#Best.2C_worst.2C_and_average_cases. If you get data where most of elements are already in place and only occassional ones are out of order, it runs in O(n) for insertion sort. It is the only reason this sort could be used in practice. Otherwise, others are far better in performance

Comment: Merge Sort is O(nlogn), no matter what the data looks like. Insertion sort is O(n^2) for unsorted data, but reaches O(n) the better the data is sorted.

Comment: @fayyazkl: if you read carefully, he said he has several sorted files, so I don't see how insertion sort will help here. it's clearly *not* going to be O(n).

Comment: @SinisterMJ: insertion sort is O(nlogn) for sorting an unsorted data set. The merge part is only O(n).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath that was a better explanation and i respect that and agreed (as reflected by the suggestion in my answer too). The point is i wasn't sure his individual file is guaranteed perfectly sorted. I instead felt there were occasional unsorted fields. At any rate, i was trying to be making some sense with an argument :) Merge will only work when he is sure, each file is perfectly sorted.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath agreed i missed the careful read :) The subject said 'mostly sorted' so that stayed at the back of my mind. Thank you. Up voting too

Answer (score 1):

How many files do you have to merge?

If it's only a few (on the order of a dozen or so) *and* each individual file is fully sorted, then you shouldn't need to build any sort of complex data structure at all: just open all the input files, read the next record from each file, compare, write the smallest to the destination, then replace that record from the appropriate file.

If each file is *not* fully sorted or if there are too many files to open at once, then yes, you will need to build an intermediate data structure in memory.  I'd recommend a self-balancing tree, but since the data are already mostly sorted, you'll be re-balancing on almost every insert.  A heap may work better for your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Sorting Algorithm:**

Insertion sort can be used efficiently for nearly sorted data (O(n) time complexity).

**Best data structure:**

Linked list is the best choice for the data structure if you are sorting it using insertion sort.

**Reason for using linked list:**

Removing and inserting elements can be done faster when elements are stored as a linked list.

Comment: Come on. It is linked list. How exactly are you going to INDEX an element in constant time in a linked list like you do in an array? Sorting any kind of link list takes roughly O(n)^3, because of sequential access vs. random access of array. Famous quote "Please never try sorting a link list in an interview" ;)

Comment: You don't essentially need random access for insertion sort. Keep in mind that if you are using array, for every element, you have to find the correct position within the sorted part, shifts all the larger/smaller values up to make a space, and inserts into that correct position. But if you are using a linked list, this insertion can be done in constant time and no elements should be shifted. So, linked list implementation can be done faster.

Comment: Hmm... perhaps i didn't look at it the way you indicated. Explanation makes sense. I didn't realize we won't be doing an index based comparison when doing insertion sort. +1